# How to reserve 'width' for a 'hide' element

Tags: html, css

What I want exactly is like *stackoverflow* comments. `hover` of comment shows vote up and flag shape for each comment. [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wrkxg/243/) is my fiddle. `hover` of element makes it move whilst I don't want moving. I want to all element be **Fixed**.

Actually my problem is: Reservation is not for `width` of an element that its `display` is `none`. How can I allocate a width for a hide element ?

It should be noted that using of `position: absolute;` is not useful. It Changes the location of the shape *(vote up)*.

Anyway, how can I implement a structure like *stackoverflow* comments ?

---

**Edit:**

HTML:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>1234</td>
    <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i></a></td>
    <td>this is comment 1</td> 
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>5</td>
    <td><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-sort-asc"></i></a></td>
    <td>this is comment 2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

CSS:

```
td{
    padding-right: 5px;
}

a{
    display: none;
}

tr:hover > td a {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  Although you have provided a link to an example, if the link were to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem.

Comment: @Paulie_D maybe you are right, ok well, I will attach some codes to my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use visibility instead of display: http://jsfiddle.net/wrkxg/244/

```
a{
    visibility: hidden;
}

tr:hover > td a {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: oh very well. just one thing, `visibility` is supported in the old browser ? Like IE 6 ?

Comment: Yes, since IE6, it is a CSS 2.1 property: http://caniuse.com/#search=css%202.1%20prop

Comment: I have a short question *(not related to the topic)*, how can I add another shape *(like a flag)* below of vote up shape ? when I add a new shape, they put next to together, but I want they put under together. please look at [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wrkxg/247/)

Answer (score 1):

when you are using `display:none` it's like the element is not exist on DOM. but using visibility property reserve place of that element in your DOM.
When you are using `hidden` value for `visibility`,The element is invisible but still takes up space.
 [HERE](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_visibility.asp) is w3schools class

so instead of `display` use `visibility` property

```
a{
 visibility: hidden;
}

tr:hover > td a {
  visibility: visible;
}
```

like [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/wrkxg/246/)

Comment: By the way, May I have your skype account ?

Comment: Thanks for +1 ;) I don't have Skype account

Comment: Your welcome, You was deserve it. And alright :-) As a advice, Create a skype account ;-) !! Each programmer *must* have one.